# rails 4, ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError for nested `accepts_nested_attributes_for` model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I have a model Offer that

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :tenant`

and Tenant model that

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :tenant_qualification`

In my controller I have:

```
@offer.assign_attributes offer_attrs
```

which triggers

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError - ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError:
  activemodel (4.2.11.3) lib/active_model/forbidden_attributes_protection.rb:23:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
```

but when in byebug I type:

`offer_attrs.permitted?` I get `true`

All the attributes received from the form are permitted,

but I byebugged the `sanitize_for_mass_assignment` just before it raises the exception, and there it gets just the attributes that are permitted for the tenant qualification, and these appear not to be permitted.

```
(byebug) pp offer_attrs
{"property_id"=>"1",
 "added_all_tenants"=>"0",
 "tenants_attributes"=>
  {"0"=>
    {"lead"=>true,
     "tenant_qualification_attributes"=>
      {"outstanding_ccj"=>"0",
       "landlord_reference"=>"1",
       "right_to_rent"=>"1",
       "employment_status"=>"Self-Employed",
       "annual_salary_pence"=>"",
       "employment_type"=>"",
       "position_type"=>"Permanent",
       "zero_hours"=>"No",
       "probation_left_months"=>"0"}
     },
     <cut>
   },
 <cut>
}
```

and my permitted attributes are:

```
params.require(:offer).permit(
  :property_id,
  :added_all_tenants,
  tenants_attributes: [
    :id,
    :lead,
    :_destroy,
    <cut>,
    tenant_qualification_attributes: %i[
      outstanding_ccj
      landlord_reference
      right_to_rent
      employment_status
      job_title
      annual_salary_pence
      employment_type
      position_type
      zero_hours
      employment_bonuses
      annual_net_salary_pence
      employment_years
      employment_months
      in_probation_period
      probation_left_months
      company_name
    ]
  ]
)
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

### Update

```
(byebug) offer_attrs.permitted?
true
(byebug) offer_attrs['tenants_attributes'].permitted?
true
(byebug) offer_attrs['tenants_attributes']['0'].permitted?
true
(byebug) offer_attrs['tenants_attributes']['0']["tenant_qualification_attributes"].permitted?
false
```

I updated the permissions to:

```
params.require(:offer).permit(
  :property_id,
  :added_all_tenants,
  { tenants_attributes: [
    :id,
    :lead,
    :_destroy,
    tenant_qualification_attributes: %i[
      outstanding_ccj
      landlord_reference
      right_to_rent
      employment_status
      job_title
      annual_salary_pence
      employment_type
      position_type
      zero_hours
      employment_bonuses
      annual_net_salary_pence
      employment_years
      employment_months
      in_probation_period
      probation_left_months
      company_name
    ],
    user_attributes: %i[
      <cut> 
    ]
  ] }
)
```

and if I change to:

```
params.require(:offer).permit(
  :property_id,
  :added_all_tenants,
  { tenants_attributes: [
    :id,
    :lead,
    :_destroy,
    tenant_qualification_attributes: [],
    user_attributes: %i[
      <cut> 
    ]
  ] }
)
```

then it works

I must be getting something wrong from here:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit

Comment: Why are you using `@offer.attributes = offer_attrs` instead of the methods like `.update` or `.assign_attributes`?

Comment: good point, it's legacy, I changed it a couple of times already, but lost the updates in a `git reset --hard`. 

changed to `.assign_attributes` but still got the same issue

Comment: I found this article, https://smartlogic.io/blog/permitting-nested-arrays-using-strong-params-in-rails/ but I don't think  that problem is what I'm experiencing.